# why my react componet still rerender after key prop changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: 1]

when i changed the key prop of react componet, i think it will destory the component immediately, but in fact, it excuted re-render and then destory the component, it makes me confused

Is there any way for the component to be destroyed directly without re-rendering and then destroying

Comment: Why do you want to prevent a rerender? Only one rerender won't affect performance in any meaningful way, and rendering a component has no side effects, so there is really no point in trying to prevent it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, if I can't avoid re-rendering, I can only do something else to avoid bugs, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible, because whenever a prop changes for a component it will re-render when the props do not comply with what you are trying to do in the component the component is destroyed.